# Hide infowindow android map api v2

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-2

I was trying to close the default infowindow in the android map.
I used `.hideInfoWindow()` but nothing appends.
Thanks.

Comment: using this method should be the right way. could you edit your question and add the important parts of your code? how do you create your markers? how do you implement the onMarkerClick-Method?

Answer (score 16):

Change the return statement

```
 @Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
return false;
}

      (to)

 @Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
return true;
}
```

Comment: returning true will not center map camera on marker!

Answer (score 11):

Use

```
    mapa.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {


                marker.hideInfoWindow();
            }
        });
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 6):

I assume you want to close the infowindow when you click the marker for the second time. It seems you need to keep track of the last clicked marker. I can't get it to work by simply checking if the clicked marker is currently shown and then close it, but this works nicely.

```
private Marker lastClicked;

private class MyMarkerClickListener implements OnMarkerClickListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        if (lastClicked != null && lastClicked.equals(marker)) {
            lastClicked = null;
            marker.hideInfoWindow();
            return true;
        } else {
            lastClicked = marker;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the pin title and snippet to null, will result in no info window being displayed. This shall cover both cases when selecting and clicking a pin.